# Issue with custom select

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a custom select which is working fine, but when the first option is selected and then another option the first option disappears from the dropdown completely. I guess usually you'd have a placeholder option that says "Select..." but I can't do that in this case.

This is the code:

```
<div class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
  <select>
    <option value="0">Audi</option>
    <option value="1">BMW</option>
    <option value="2">Citroen</option>
    <option value="3">Ford</option>
  </select>
</div>


<script>
    var x, i, j, selElmnt, a, b, c;
      /*look for any elements with the class "custom-select":*/
      x = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-select");
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        selElmnt = x[i].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
        /*for each element, create a new DIV that will act as the selected item:*/
        a = document.createElement("DIV");
        a.setAttribute("class", "select-selected");
        a.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
        x[i].appendChild(a);
        /*for each element, create a new DIV that will contain the option list:*/
        b = document.createElement("DIV");
        b.setAttribute("class", "select-items select-hide");
        for (j = 1; j < selElmnt.length; j++) {
          /*for each option in the original select element,
          create a new DIV that will act as an option item:*/
          c = document.createElement("DIV");
          c.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[j].innerHTML;
          c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
              /*when an item is clicked, update the original select box,
              and the selected item:*/
              var y, i, k, s, h;
              s = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
              h = this.parentNode.previousSibling;
              for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
                if (s.options[i].innerHTML == this.innerHTML) {
                  s.selectedIndex = i;
                  h.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
                  y = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("same-as-selected");
                  for (k = 0; k < y.length; k++) {
                    y[k].removeAttribute("class");
                  }
                  this.setAttribute("class", "same-as-selected");
                  break;
                }
              }
              h.click();
          });
          b.appendChild(c);
        }
        x[i].appendChild(b);
        a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            /*when the select box is clicked, close any other select boxes,
            and open/close the current select box:*/
            e.stopPropagation();
            closeAllSelect(this);
            this.nextSibling.classList.toggle("select-hide");
            this.classList.toggle("select-arrow-active");
        });
      }
      function closeAllSelect(elmnt) {
        /*a function that will close all select boxes in the document,
        except the current select box:*/
        var x, y, i, arrNo = [];
        x = document.getElementsByClassName("select-items");
        y = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected");
        for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
          if (elmnt == y[i]) {
            arrNo.push(i)
          } else {
            y[i].classList.remove("select-arrow-active");
          }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
          if (arrNo.indexOf(i)) {
            x[i].classList.add("select-hide");
          }
        }
      }
      /*if the user clicks anywhere outside the select box,
      then close all select boxes:*/
      document.addEventListener("click", closeAllSelect);
</script>
```

I've created  a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v9yrq0go/) to make it more clear what I mean.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't seem to be dropping the previously selected options.

Comment: @nocturns2 it only does it the first time you select something so the 'Audi' disappears when you select something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this JavaScript Code

```
for (j = 0; j < selElmnt.length; j++) {
```

Instead of

```
for (j = 1; j < selElmnt.length; j++) {
```

Check this https://jsfiddle.net/v9yrq0go/1

Answer (score 1):

you are appending from 1 not from 0.. Use below code

```
 var x, i, j, selElmnt, a, b, c;
      /*look for any elements with the class "custom-select":*/
      x = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-select");
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        selElmnt = x[i].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
        /*for each element, create a new DIV that will act as the selected item:*/
        a = document.createElement("DIV");
        a.setAttribute("class", "select-selected");
        a.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
        x[i].appendChild(a);
        /*for each element, create a new DIV that will contain the option list:*/
        b = document.createElement("DIV");
        b.setAttribute("class", "select-items select-hide");
        for (j = 0; j < selElmnt.length; j++) {
          /*for each option in the original select element,
          create a new DIV that will act as an option item:*/
          c = document.createElement("DIV");
          c.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[j].innerHTML;
          c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
              /*when an item is clicked, update the original select box,
              and the selected item:*/
              var y, i, k, s, h;
              s = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
              h = this.parentNode.previousSibling;
              for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
                if (s.options[i].innerHTML == this.innerHTML) {
                  s.selectedIndex = i;
                  h.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
                  y = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("same-as-selected");
                  for (k = 0; k < y.length; k++) {
                    y[k].removeAttribute("class");
                  }
                  this.setAttribute("class", "same-as-selected");
                  break;
                }
              }
              h.click();
          });
          b.appendChild(c);
        }
        x[i].appendChild(b);
        a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            /*when the select box is clicked, close any other select boxes,
            and open/close the current select box:*/
            e.stopPropagation();
            closeAllSelect(this);
            this.nextSibling.classList.toggle("select-hide");
            this.classList.toggle("select-arrow-active");
        });
      }
```